# Load data set directly into Array Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, range

I have a short subroutine where I ask the user to specify a starting date using an Inputbox. Currently I copy the starting date to a cell (eg., "A1"), and then use EDate function to advance the date by month for 11 more months to give me a year of dates in Column A, rows 1 through 12.

The code is below:

```
Sub daterng()
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue

Message = "Enter a date in month/day/year format"    ' Set prompt.
Title = "Create Date Range"
Default = "10/1/2020"
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
Range("A1") = MyValue

For x = 2 To 12
    Cells(x, 1) = "=EDATE(A" & x - 1 & ", 1)"    'Advances date in A1 by a month for 11 months to A2:A12
Next x
End Sub
```

This works well, and I can then use the range for other purposes.  What I would like to do, however, is to assign the values created by the MyValue variable and loop directly to an array. I would like to bypass creating the range altogether - just pass the MyValue value (e.g., "10/1/2020") and resulting 11 months directly into an array.  Not sure how to do this.  Another issue is that the formula - EDATE - would need to be rewritten to accept the MyValue variable. Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, it might be helpful to people in the future if you post your findings as an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I asked the question prematurely as I think I figured it out.
Here is the revised code below. It reads a value into the variable MyValue, then loads 12 date values - advanced one month at a time via EDate - into the array "arr". Then I establish a range where I want the array to print out, then set the range equal to the array.

```
Sub dtearray()
Dim arr(12) As Variant, rng As Range, c As Long

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 14))
MyValue = "10/1/2020"

For c = 0 To UBound(arr)
    arr(c) = WorksheetFunction.EDate(MyValue, c)
Next c

rng = arr
End Sub
```